# How to slide navigation bar properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a website http://hadeyaa.com . When I view website in mobile, the navigation bar gets converted into bar, I am using [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples.html) plugin for this. But that bar is not sliding properly when clicked. Can anyone help me, how to inspect it or where to look in for details.

following is the code for navigation bar for mobile;

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"></a>
</div>
```

Following is the link of mobile site;
http://mobt.me/NTHW

Following is the pic of what I want to explain. (This says it all)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

Remove the margin from the class (.sliderMT) in style.css and give the padding.

like this:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZKdG.jpg)

.sliderMT {

```
padding-top: 92px;
```

}

Comment: did you removed the margin from this class  .sliderMT ?

Comment: Please Try this .sliderMT {
    padding-top: 32px;
}